# External access to the sender in Patterns.ask()

Tags: java, akka, distributed-computing, actor

I need to access the **sender** actor when **Patterns.ask()** call is made. Example:

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("MySystem");
ActorRef actor = system.create(..., "MyActor");
Future<Object> futureResult = Patterns.ask(actor, new Question(), 10000);
```

Here the Akka framework will **send a message** to the **"MyActor"** actor which will have to respond to it by: `getSender().tell(...)`.

The sender will be an actor created by the Akka framework - it's path might look like this: `akka://MySystem/temp/$a`). **How** can I be able to get the **ActorRef** of this actor?

I have the path given above but when I call `system.actorSelection` and then use `resolveOne` I get an error saying that this actor is not existing (Note: I know that this sender actor will be killed right after the answer is received - the test I made are even before `getSender().tell()` method is invoked).

This came up as a problem when a updated the Akka version in my project to **2.5.4**. Before that I had no problem accessing **temp/sender** actors.

I have read about `Patterns.ask(ActorRef actor, Function<ActorRef,java.lang.Object> messageFactory, Timeout timeout)` but did not manage to utilize it because I am struggling with the idea behind of it (could not find examples also). So, if the above method is somewhat of a solution can you guys give me an **example usage** of it?

If any of my statements above are **not** fully **true** or wrong - please make your corrections! :)

**Thank you** for your time!

Comment: > How can I be able to get the ActorRef of this actor?
What's the point of doing that? The response message will be ignored by the temp actor anyway.

Comment: Because my business logic requires it - I am building an API which provides **creation of actors** in a system. At some point (when the actual `Patterns.ask()` is called) my API will be **asked** for this temporary actor. That's because the client determines what the behaviour of the actor is. To do so my client implements a **function** which is **expecting** three things: **selfActor**, **senderActor** and the **message** itself.

Comment: I also don't get what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by "determines what the behaviour of the actor is": a) find out what the actor is doing, or b) set the behaviour of the actor? A) is easy: it is setting the content of a single message as value of a promise, and b) makes no sense because you wouldn't use ask() but create your own actor. Also, let's say you obtain the actor ref, what are you going to do with it, how is it supposed to be used? I fail to see anything meaningful as `MyActor` will send it an answer, then your actor will be gone and the ref won't be valid anyway.

Comment: See [link](https://pastebin.com/XSTywDsL).

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem was by wrapping the original message in a let's say "AskMessage" class. Then when receiving such a message my actor will create a temp actor which solely purpose is to process that one message. After that the actor will be stopped. This actor will notify for the result of through the internal API of my application.